# Jackson Mapping to a Map variable

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class which has a Map as one of the variable.
Jackson parser is unable to map to this.

Example -

```
Class A
{
private String abc;

private Map<String, String> xyz;
...

}
```

In Controller i have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myval", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =
{ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    @ResponseBody
    public DGF updateCall(@RequestBody final A varName)
{
....
}



Json
{
"abc":"tyui",
"xyz":[{
"key" : "rtyu",
"value" : "yui"
}]
...
}
```

When debugging getting xyz as null .

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an actual [mcve]. Do you ever set `xyz` to anything, like `xyz = new HashMap<String, String>()`?

Comment: @JonnyHenly - I have updated the xplaination. Please let me know if it makes sense .

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a non-parameter constructor for Class A, in order to get Jackson deserializing working:

```
public A (){
abc="";
xyz = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
```

Comment: How do you know that OP doesn't have a non-parameter constructor for `Class A`? Following the declaration of `xyz` in their code, is three dots (`...`) which usually means they have omitted code. Please wait to answer questions until they are answerable.

Comment: @motagirl2 :- Thanks for the reply.
So if i have 10 variable i need to initialize all of them in  non-parameter constructor

Comment: Correct, @AbhilashJain